# PHP development without xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I have machine on which I lack admin privileges. I was not able to install xampp server on it. So I tried portable version of xampp. But I was getting error while starting Apache server and MySQL. The log file is not getting created.

Also many tutorials online use NetBeans which is also I am not able to install due lack of admin privileges.

I have postgres and apache tomcat working on my machine, which I used for Java Spring development. I also have eclipse installed on my machine. So I was thinking if I can manually configure eclipse, postgres, tomcat to develop php without installing xampp or netbeans.

Is it possible? If yes how do I do it? Is there any tutorial / link / webpage explaining the same?

Comment: Sounds like a great case for spinning up a VM.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install jetbrains PhpStorm it has a built in server but due to lack of privileges i think it is not posiible though, so here are two links i have for you, hope you will able to find an answer..

https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-EclipseDbWebapps/index.html

https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-connect-postgres-database-using-eclipse-and-netbeans

Answer (score 0):

if you use php framework like laravel, cakephp etc.
Those have own development server to run application.
and for the database you can use sqlite database.
that not require xampp server